# How to Properly Start a Session in PHP?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables, deprecated

I was recently following a tutorial on how to make a custom CMS for my website. I am currently making the back end, so the users can create and edit pages. The tutorial is kind of old so various functions have been deprecated. I was able to fix most of them, except for the "session_register();" function. I saw on many sites, including this one that told me to use "$_SESSION['admin']=$username;" for example. This is not working for me, since I apply this to many pages, each page is asking me to re-enter the information.

Here are files I am using:

admin_check.php:

```
<?php
$error_msg="";
if ($_POST['username']){
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Simple hard coded values for the correct username and password
$admin="Admin";
$adminpass="Password";
//connect to mysql here if you store admin username and password in your database
//This would be the prefered method of storing the values instead of hard coding them here into the script
if(($username !=$admin)||($password != $adminpass)){
    $error_msg='<h3 class="text-danger">Login information incorrect, please try again.</h3>';
} else{
    $_SESSION['admin']=$username;
    require_once "index.php";
    exit();
}
}
?>

<?php
if ($_SESSION['admin']!="Admin"){
echo '<div class="container" style="background-color: #FFF ;"><h3><i   class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert text-danger"></i> Solo los administradores
      tienen permiso para ver este directorio. No se admite gente con Lag!        </h3><br/>

      <!DOCTYPE html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Administrador</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">       
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-    glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
      <body style="padding-top: 5px; background-color: #EEE ;">
    <div style="max-width: 450px; max-height: 550px; background-color: #CCC; padding-top: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 15px #DDD; border-radius: 10px" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #fff; max-height: 470px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 2; box-shadow: 0 0 12px #777;">
            <legend class="text-success">LOGIN ADMINISTRATOR</legend>
            <hr />                
            <p style="font-size: 12pt;">Please enter your username and password to login into the admin site.</p>
            <form action="admin_check.php" method="post" target="_self" class="form-group">
                <label class="label label-default">username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username">
                <br/>                    
                <label class="label label-default">password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn-success" value="submit" type="submit" name="button" id="button" >Submit</button>
            </form><br/>
            '.$error_msg.'
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<br/><br/>

         <center> <a href="../" >Click aquí para regresar a un lugar seguro.</a>    </div></center>';


    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

^ As you can see, this is where the admins input the username and password, which I'd like to have stored somehow, like in a cookie, so they can navigate freely without having to input the username and password over and over again.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "admin_check.php";?>
<?php
include "admin_header.php";
?>
<body id="home">
    <div class="container" style="background-color: white;">
        <h2 style="color: #FF691F"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> Home</h2>
    </div>
</body>        
<?php include "admin_footer.php"; ?>
```

create_blog.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once "admin_check.php";?>
<?php
include "admin_header.php";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_form(){
    valid=true;
    if(document.form.pagetitle.value===""){
        alert("Please Enter a Page Title!");
        valid=false;
    }else if{
        alert("Please Enter Keywords about this Page!");
        valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_form1(){
    valid=true;
    if(document.form.pid.value===""){
        alert("Please Enter a Page ID!");
        valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
</script>

<body id="blog">
<div class="container" style="background-color: white; box-shadow: 0 -5px 9px 3px #b2b2b2;">
    <br/>
    <h2 style="color: #777 ;"><i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"></i> Upload Blog Entry</h2>
    <p class="text-danger text-center">Title, Body, and Keywords are required to create new post! None should be left blank!</p>
    <a href="mmoAdmin/"><h6 class="text-muted pull-right"><< Back Home</h6>  </a>
    <br/>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit_blog.php" onsubmit="return validate_form1();" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn-default" type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Edit Post">Edit Post</button>
        </div>
        <input name="pid" type="text" id="pid" size="8" maxlength="11" class="form-control"/>
        <span id="helpBlock1" class="help-block">Enter the ID of the post you want to edit. eg: "blog/article.php?pid=<'this is the id'>"</span>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="delete_blog.php" onsubmit="return validate_form2();" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn-default" type="submit" id="button3" name="button3" value="Delete Post">Delete Post</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pid" name="pid"/></div>
        <span id="helpBlock2" class="help-block">Enter the ID of the post you want to delete. eg: "blog/article.php?pid=<'this is the id'>"</span>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="congrat_blog.php" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="pagetitle" id="pagetitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title..." value="<?php echo $pagetitle; ?>"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Body</label>
        <textarea name="pagebody" id="pagebody" style="height: 480px; width: 100%" ><?php echo $pagebody; ?></textarea>
        <br/>
        <label>Keywords</label>
        <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="blog, mmob, etc..." value="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-success" name="button" id="button"   value="Create this page now">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>


<?php include "admin_footer.php"; ?>
```

^Like this I have multiple pages, all with the php function "session_start();" at the beginning of the document, and I included_once the "admin_check.php" with the "$_SESSION['admin']=$username" function on all of them.

Note: admin_header.php, and admin_footer.php are just HTML header navbar and footer, so I don't have to correct those for individual pages.

I am fairly new to php. Am I on the correct path of doing this?
Basically all I am trying to is a login feature so that the admins can access a back end which will let them upload information into a database, so it populates the site.

Here is the link of the tutorial series I've been following to create this basic CMS:

[How to Build PHP and MySQL CMS Website Software](https://youtu.be/UUMq-yBVlrM)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: question is, did you start the session for admin_check.php?

Comment: `session_start();` on top will start session properly and automatically. But wherever you want to access data from session or to manipulate session data or to store data into session, `session_start();` will compulsory on that page.

Comment: A call to `session_start()` before accessing `$_SESSION[]` is all you need. Forget about `session_register()`, `session_is_registered()` and `session_unregister()`. They do not exist anymore and they were useless since more than 10 years ago.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add session_start() in admin_check.php:

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, I might be the stupidest person in the world... I was following the tutorial letter by letter, since I am new in PHP. The tutorial didn't include the "session_start();" on the "admin_check.php". So I didn't add it. I just tried, and everything works like a charm.   I guess there was no need for "session_start();" at "admin_check.php" on the version of PHP on the tutorial.

Comment: @JosephMontes Hey... things happen and no one has code embedded in their DNA at birth ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @JosephMontes when ever follow a tutorial, please check the post date. you will come to know how older it is. try to follow latest posts.

Comment: well, people are just all over my comment down there, *huh?* lol

Comment: @Anant hehe, I know and Stack changed the colors a bit lately, have you noticed? *lol* it's not as "green" anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that tutorial didn't mention having to start the session in every page, but it does.

Therefore `session_start();` but be part of all files using sessions.

Error reporting would have helped you here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Another thing that tutorial may not have covered is "passwords".

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

If you plan on using a database later on, use [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

- This is just an insight.

Comment: Yes, it is a pretty basic tutorial. It mentioned to have session_start(); on every document but not on the admin_check.php. I even downloaded the source code from the tut, and there was no session_start(); on the admin_check.php. So I had no idea. As I said, I am new on php, and I am teaching myself.   Thanks a lot for the help! You're all awesome!

Comment: downvoter, care to explain? or it's probably that... guy. *sigh* - pffft :p

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. It's a change from seeing green all the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you've forgotten `session_start()` at the start of your PHP file, it would be a good idea to put this at the top of your PHP file, so that sessions will work. This usually sets (or uses an already passed) cookies which then identifies the user so `$_SESSION` variables will work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: That was the answer! I was just following the tutorial letter by letter.There was no session_start(); on the admin_check.php , so I thought you didn't need the session_start(); on the admin_check.php file. Now I know! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You forgot to start session before setting session in your code.

**Solution :**
Replace your first portion of code with this one fixed :

```
<?php
session_start();
$error_msg="";
if ($_POST['username']){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    // Simple hard coded values for the correct username and password
    $admin="Admin";
    $adminpass="Password";
    //connect to mysql here if you store admin username and password in your database
    //This would be the prefered method of storing the values instead of hard coding them here into the script
    if(($username !=$admin)||($password != $adminpass)){
        $error_msg='<h3 class="text-danger">Login information incorrect, please try again.</h3>';
    } else{
        $_SESSION['admin']=$username;
        require_once "index.php";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

**Note :** Remember to run the `session_start()` statement on your pages before you try to access the `$_SESSION` array or trying to set one, and also before any output is sent to the browser.

**Reference URL :**

> http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I am the stupidest person on php land. I was just following the tutorial letter by letter, and there was no session_start(); on the admin_check.php from the tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: @JosephMontes : No Problem.you are welcome...! Don't hesitate to ask for more help if you need at all..!